# PSIM: thyristor acting as a diode in a full bridge rectifier with C filter

Tags: filter, bridge-rectifier, thyristor

We were asked to simulate a controlled bridge rectifier with C filter for class.
Whatever I change the firing angle into, the output stays the same (Same Vdc).
I thought that a capacitor filter couldn't force a thyrsitor to stay on and that was only an inductor.

pictures included:
alpha 60:
[image: Alpha 60 circuit]
[image: Alpha 60 output]

alpha 0:
[image: Alpha 0 circuit]
[image: Alpha 0 output]

Comment: How are you firing your thyristors? If you fire before the peak voltage, then the capacitor will tend to make the output voltage constant unless you have a heavy load. At the peak voltage, the capacitor will be fully charged.

Comment: If your drivers are correct, you should see a varying level of DC output depending on the firing angle. If you don't, then you're not driving them correctly.

Comment: I'm using a gating block to fire my thyristors as seen in the pictures. I'm firing at an angle of 60 degrees. How can I drive it differently so that it works. Also when I remove the capacitor it works normally (fires at 60).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the capacitor. You see, when using a controlled rectifier, if a Capacitor is present, it will charge the capacitor with the input voltage source with the maximum value of \$v_{i}(t)\$, after it is cut by the switching. Since your angle is bellow 90 degrees, you will always pass through the maximum value.

As such, I would suggest you to stick with switching angles between 90 and 180 degrees.

Here are some curves showing the behaviour.

Simulated rectifier:

[image: Controlled Rectifier]

Curves with \$\alpha=90^\circ\$:

[image: Curve with alpha = 90 degrees]

Curves with \$\alpha=135^\circ\$:

[image: Curve with alpha = 135 degrees]

P.S.: The curves were obtained with PSIM 2020 demo.
P.S.S.: As a bonus, it is recomended to, after switching the thyristors, to remove the gattling signal.